# ByteBuddy Agent: If intercepting methods, the JUnit test fail

Tags: java, junit, byte-buddy

I am trying to analyse JUnit tests with ByteBuddy (1.7.5) dynamically, so I don't know them in advance. I am loading them through the run() method below, and intercepting with the Agent built with the Agent() method below.

The unit tests work as expected when I run them directly in Eclipse or when I run them without installing the agent. But as soon as the Agent gets installed, the tests throw exceptions and fail.

For example: `java.io.FileNotFoundException` are thrown when the test creates documents (see stack trace below). I am using opensource unit tests (in this case  from [terrier-core](https://github.com/terrier-org/terrier-core), the tests in the test class `org.terrier.indexing.TestSimpleXMLCollection`).

Does someone know why this happens? Is it something like a race condition happening with the original test and the interceptor?

My code is the following:

```
public void run(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class classWithName, String testMethodName) {
        interceptor.traversed = false;
        Request request = Request.method(classWithName, testMethodName);
        junit.run(request);
}
```

And:

```
public Agent(String pn) {
        this.projectName = pn;
        this.junit = new JUnitCore();
        this.interceptor = new InterceptorX2();

        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(
                ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.named("junit.framework.testcase"))
                .and(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWithIgnoreCase(projectName)
                        .or(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWithIgnoreCase("test"))
                        .or(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWithIgnoreCase("tests")))
                ,
                ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isBootstrapClassLoader()))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                    @Override
                    public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription arg1, ClassLoader arg2, JavaModule arg3) {
                        return builder
                                .method(
                                        ElementMatchers.isPublic()
                                        .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Object.class))
                                        .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(junit.framework.TestCase.class))))
                                ).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor));
                    }

                }).installOn(ByteBuddyAgent.install());
    }
```

**EDIT:**

And my interceptor is doing nothing special:

```
@RuntimeType
public Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @SuperCall Callable<?> zuper, @AllArguments Object[] args, @This Object thiz) throws Exception {
        return zuper.call();
}
```

Stacktrace of error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Temp\junit6014103019704928063\terrier.properties (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.terrier.tests.ApplicationSetupBasedTest.makeEnvironment$original$m3joH5OH(ApplicationSetupBasedTest.java:81)
    at org.terrier.tests.ApplicationSetupBasedTest.makeEnvironment$original$m3joH5OH$accessor$c8PeV6zd(ApplicationSetupBasedTest.java)
    at org.terrier.tests.ApplicationSetupBasedTest$auxiliary$fr9IrFTX.call(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.bytebuddy.introspect.InterceptorX2.intercept(InterceptorX2.java:79)
    at org.terrier.tests.ApplicationSetupBasedTest.makeEnvironment(ApplicationSetupBasedTest.java)
    at org.terrier.indexing.TestSimpleXMLCollection.makeEnvironment$accessor$BjbiedTZ(TestSimpleXMLCollection.java)
    at org.terrier.indexing.TestSimpleXMLCollection$auxiliary$BcvkPOor.call(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.bytebuddy.introspect.InterceptorX2.intercept(InterceptorX2.java:79)
    at org.terrier.indexing.TestSimpleXMLCollection.makeEnvironment(TestSimpleXMLCollection.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at myproject.bytebuddy.introspect.Agent.run(Agent.java:71)
    at myproject.analysis.MutatorAnalysis.runAgent(MutatorAnalysis.java:43)
    at myproject.Analysis.getResultsForTestCase(Analysis.java:196)
    at myproject.Analysis.startPrivateAnalysis(Analysis.java:163)
    at myproject.Analysis.start(Analysis.java:147)
```

Comment: This is too little information to help you. What files are those exceptions about. What does your interceptor change?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter - I added some informations to my question. But since I analyze open source code and the code is to long to paste, I've given a link to the project)

Comment: The produced stack traces would be more interesting in this case. Are there chained exceptions somewhere added to the trace?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter - I added the Stacktrace. The only exception thrown is the FileNotFoundException;.

Comment: Did you set a break point in the interceptor and check if the file `C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Temp\junit6014103019704928063\terrier.properties` exists?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter - the files aren't created. I figured out that `InterceptorX2.equals(String)` is called (i never used or implemented it) by the external code istead of the method creating the missing files. I don't know why... The method that should have been called is a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.